# Combinatorics problems: termination at rth step

Tags: combinatorics, self-learning

In Feller's book of probability exixt such formulas:
a)Placing balls untill for the first time a ball is placed into a cell already occupied:

1. The probability of the process termitating at the rth step is:$$((n)r *(r-1))/n^r$$
2. The probability that process lasts for more than r steps: $$ (n)r/n^r$$

b)Continue procedure of placing balls as long as this cell remains empty:

1. The probability that the process terminates at the rth step: $$ ((n-1)/n)^{r-1} *1/n $$
2. Probability that the process lasts for more than r steps:$$(1-1/n)^r$$

Can you please explain how we got formulas? And the examples of their usage.
Thank you

Comment: Is $n(r)$ the product $nr$ or is it $n(n-1)(n-2)\dots(n-r+1)=\frac {n!}{r!}$?

Answer (score 1):

I would start with a(2).  When you put the first ball in, you have $n$ empty bins out of $n$, so the chance the process continues past the first step is $\frac nn$.  When you put the second ball in, the process continues with probability $\frac{n-1}n$.  When you put the third in, the chance it continues (assuming you get this far) is $\frac {n-2}n$ because two bins are occupied.  The chance you get past the third ball is then $\frac {n(n-1)(n-2}{n^3}$.  The same logic says the chance of getting past $r$ balls is $\frac {n(n-1)(n-2)\dots(n-r+1)}{n^r}=\frac{n!}{n^rr!}$  I believe the numerator is what you are calling $(n)r$.  The others are done similarly-see if you can.

Comment: Thank you!That is clear, but can you also, if it possible, clear me other three cocnepte, because now i cannot get it

Comment: For a(1) you have to not stop in $r-1$ steps (use the above), then stop at the $r^{\text{th}}$ step.  What is the chance of that?  I get a different result than you quote.